# Reference to type GoogleMap.IOnCameraMoveListener claims it is defined in Xamarin.GooglePlayServices

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm facing an issue related with a reference, as the title shows I'm getting:

> Reference to type 'GoogleMap.IOnCameraMoveListener' claims it is
>   defined in 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps', but it could not be
>   found     C:\Users\App.Xamarin\App.Android\CustomMapRenderer.cs

I been trying to use the live player on a Samsung Galaxy S8+ Android API 27 with no success.

```
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using App.Android;
using App.Portable.Vista.ControlesUsuario.Mapas;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MapaGoogle), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace App.Android
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
    {
        List<Position> routeCoordinates;
        bool isDrawn;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (MapaGoogle)e.NewElement;
                routeCoordinates = formsMap.RouteCoordinates;
                Control.GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName.Equals("VisibleRegion") && !isDrawn)
            {
                var polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                polylineOptions.InvokeColor(0x66FF0000);

                foreach (var position in routeCoordinates)
                {
                    polylineOptions.Add(new LatLng(position.Latitude, position.Longitude));
                }

                NativeMap.AddPolyline(polylineOptions);
                isDrawn = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I spent 2 days already trying to figure out what's going on but it is quite hard to find a solution as the error is too specific if I am not mistaken.

I only found [this link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android/MapRenderer.cs) with relevant information.

Also, I do not know if it is related with the NuGet packages that require updates GooglePlayServices, Forms and so on. However, whenever I update them the references are missed in the whole solution.

Any help will be highly appreciated !

Cheers,

Eric R.

Comment: Could u add MapaGoogle code?

Comment: Use simulators or real device to test it. Live player can't be used with custom renderer. See more limitations: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations?tabs=android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations?tabs=android)